# Get reference to variable and avoid copying it unnecessarily

Tags: c#, reference

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Array{
    int[] values;
}
```

Now suppose I have a class that stores a lot of `Array`s:

```
class ArrayOfArrays{
    Array[] arrays;
}
```

Suppose, for some reason, I want to get the last `Array` of `arrays` and put in a variable (for better readability). In C, I would do like `Array last = &ArrayOfArraysObject.arrays[lastIndex]`. As I won't modify it, for better performance, I don't need to copy the whole array, just a reference do the job.

Can I have this kind of behaviour in C# ? (without using function calls, I don't want to create a function just to use the keyword `ref`, it looks like overkill)

Comment: How about a property that returns the last element?

Comment: That wouldn't be much different from accessing directly `ArrayOfArraysObject.arrays[lastIndex]`. For readability (and to keep efficiency), I'd prefer to create something like a reference variable, if it possible.

Comment: It does keep the reference.

Comment: For those rusty on our C, If you did `Array last = &ArrayOfArraysObject.arrays[lastIndex]` then the next line replaced the last entry in the in the outer `Array[]` with a new array would the object `last` references change?

Comment: In C, it would, in my case, doesn't matter. I won't modify the array, just wanna access it in a variable with a understandable name without having to copy the whole thing.

Comment: @Sach does it? If I create a function inside `ArrayOfArrays` that returns the last element of `arrays`, AFAIK it would return a copy of the element.

Comment: Yes. In `C#` it doesn't create a "Deep" copy of an object by default. References are maintained instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `public` property that returns the last element of `arrays`.

```
class ArrayOfArrays
{
    Array[] arrays;

    public Array LastOfArrays { get { return arrays.Last(); } }
}
```

### Test it:

```
var aoa = new ArrayOfArrays();
// Initialize and enter data here

//When you want to use the last item:
var last = aoa.LastOfArrays;
last.values[0] = 333;
```

Now, `aoa.arrays[LastElement].values[0]` would also be `333`. So you essentially do keep the reference here, and does not copy the entire array.

### Confirmation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Arrays already use references in C#. You don't have to do anything special, and you get the behavior you want:

```
int[][] foo = new int[][] { new int[] {1,2,3}, new int[]{4,5,6}, new int[]{7,8,9} };        
var bar = foo[2];
foo[2][2] = 0; // make a change **after** assigning to bar  
Console.WriteLine(bar[2]); // outputs "0" -- bar knows about the change

bar[1] = 6; // same thing, but in reverse
Console.WriteLine(foo[2][1]); // outputs "6" -- foo knows about the change
```

In the example above, `foo[2]` and `bar` are references to the **same array** in memory. `bar` was *not* just a copy.

Comment: Would it make a difference if instead of `Array[] arrays`, it was `List<Array> arrays`?

Comment: Only if the number of items in the list changes, where you care about knowing which is _last_. The `bar` reference in my example would still work, but it will continue to refer to the _same array_, even if that array is no longer last.